# Examples of two different vector space topologies with same continuous functionals

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces

**Question:** Given a vector space $V$, is it possible to endow it with two different vector space topologies $\mathcal T_1$ and $\mathcal T_2$ such that any linear functional on $V$ is continuous in the sense of $\mathcal T_1$ if only if it is continuous in the sense of $\mathcal T_2$?

By a vector space topology I mean a topology such that vector addition and scalar multiplication are continuous.

I think it is quite a basic question, but I couldn't work out a answer.

**Edit:** Before I asked this question, I was actually thinking whether the the dual of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ remains the same when the space is given the usual topology of test functions and the subspace topology of $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$. Indeed I didn't think through the general question before I posted it on this site, and I didn't mean to do it that this question became a "hot network question".

Comment: The space of all finitely non-zero sequences with $\ell^{p}$ and $\ell^{q}$ metrics with $p,q \in (0,1), p \neq q$ is an example. The dual is $\{0\}$ for both of these metrics.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you! But I think it would be much harder to find an example for normed spaces. Maybe I should ask another question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a basic fact:

Let $V$ be a topological vector space (with topology $\tau_1$). Consider the weak topology $\tau_2$ on $V$ ( given by the duality $V\times V^{\star}\to k$). Then $V$ with $\tau_2$ has the same topological dual as $V$ with $\tau_1$ (easy to prove).

$\bf{Added:}$ Conclusion: for a topological vector space $(V, \tau_1)$, the weak topology on $V$ is the smallest topology having the same dual. I think there exists the notion of the strongest topology with the same dual. Maybe related to bornological spaces? I vaguely remember it. Reference: Schaeffer - Topological Vector spaces

$\bf{Added:}$ As @Jochen mentioned,  the strongest topology  is the [Mackey topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackey_topology) .